# Systemd set autostart=always for services without editing service files manually

Tags: linux, service, systemd

This question is about services in general and rabbitmq in particular. The system is Debian. I want rabbitmq to restart automatically. Now I don't want to add the Restart=always manually but by a script. After looking around for while by now I don't find a solution besides changing the service files manually.

Is there any command or systemd setting I can use to set the Restart value for a specific service? Or is there a hidden parameter for apt-get install where I can set this value?

Of course I could use a script to find the string in the service file but I am wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to do this.

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: What do you mean exactly. By now my effort is crawling the internet with various search terms and finding no solution. Right now I found out that the sysv-generator generates the service-files out from sources which I try to find.

Comment: I mean, did you google it?

Comment: Yes... That's what I meant with crawling the internet.

Comment: On Debian Jessie there is even no rabbitmq-server.service file after installing with apt-get while it exists on Kubuntu in /lib/systemd/system. But that's another story, I guess